# Keep an index for how many times a if statement had passed inside a list comprehension

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

I want for a vector with ones and zeros to check if the element in the vector is 1. If it is one I want to label this element 2 and the next one is equal to 3 etc..
This is easily done by a for loop.

```
x=np.array([1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.])

def label(vector):
U=np.copy(vector)
l=2
for i in range(len(U[:])):
    if occupied(U[i]):
        U[i]=l
        l+=1
return U
```

And then

```
label(x)
```

returns

array([2., 0., 0., 3., 0., 0., 4., 0., 5., 0.])

However since ths arrays become larger and eventually become matrices I thought I would be a good idea to use list comprehensions.

```
def count_clusters(vector):
U=np.copy(vector)
label=2
U[:] = [label, label+=1 if el==1. else el for el in U[:]]
return U
```

Which should look something like this. 
The problem is ofcourse to do the label+=1 at the same time in the list comprehension as to change the value of the element in the array. And then afterwards use the label+1 for the following label.

So I was wondering if this is possible or should I just stick to the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same using iterator and make use of `next()`:

```
import numpy as np

U = np.array([1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.])
c = iter(range(2, len(U)+2))

result = [float(next(c)) if x == 1 else x for x in U]
# [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0]
```

Also this is another way using `itertools.count`:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import count

U = np.array([1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.])
c = count(2)

result = [float(next(c)) if x == 1 else x for x in U]
# [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: This works. How can I add a second statement that when I have two ones next to each other. The right one becomes the same label as the one on the left, but without raising the label.

Comment: Hi, your original question is answered. You can post a whole new question for further questions. If you feel helpful, mark the helpful answer as accepted by pressing tick on left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not optimized for speed but funny and without numpy.

```
def label(vector):
    return [sum(vector[:i+1]) * x for i, x in enumerate(vector)]

assert label([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]) == [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3]
```

And the same with numpy.

```
import numpy as np

def label(vector):
    return np.cumsum(vector) * vector

assert (label([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]) == np.array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3])).all()
```